# Java jar launcher for console only apps mac

Tags: java, macos, launcher

I want to bundle my .jar app to automatically run open on mac os. It has no GUI so it needs to be run from terminal to work but I need to give it to others who would rather not use terminal.
How would I go about doing this? I tried the app builder that is seen [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/packagingAppsForMac.html) but it only shows up on activity monitor for a fraction of a second before going away.
More info about my jar file:
It was build in netbeans so it does have all the folders/xml needed to build a jar via ant. It needs a few additional libraries that are copied to the lib folder when netbeans builds the project. Thirdly it needs to store temp files in a folder called assets that is located in the same folder as the jar file is. I can change number 3 if need be.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue doesn't really have much to do with running on the mac - the problem is that you're trying to run a console app without a console.

[Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/328417/Java-Console-apps-made-easy) is an example of one way to provide a console in a GUI window, rather than running the app in an shell (the terminal).

Once you have that working, you can consider wrapping it in the Mac - specific deployment that you pointed to.

For portability's sake, you may also want to consider:

- Re-packaging your classes and all of the classes from your jar dependencies into one big "uber-jar" - there are several tools for doing this, including the Maven Assembly Plugin
- Storing your temporary files in the system's default temp file location (using File.createTempFile) instead of specifying exactly where they should be written.